# php is not recognized as an internal or external command (windows 7)

Tags: php, command-line, xampp

I added php to the PATH environment var. Showing here my last three entries in the path input:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\xampp\php\
```

Somehow when I run `php -v` in the cmd I still get the *not recognized as an internal or external command* error.

Any ideas on how should I fix this?

[image: xampp php folder screenshot]

Comment: Check if php.exe is in `C:\xampp\php\` or some subfolder there

Comment: Pretty sure it's there. Added a screenshot.

Comment: Reopen your cmd window after you have added the path, then the change will have an effect

Comment: I think you need to restart the computer to take effect the changes you have made in path.

Comment: I've restarted my PC multiple times after modifying the variable system with no luck.

Comment: restart will be needed or at last : http://www.nerdydork.com/update-windows-path-without-rebooting.html

Comment: have you tried to use "C:\xampp\php" instead of "C:\xampp\php" not sure if it makes anz difference under windows

Comment: Ugh, Windows was a long time ago here... perhaps the ending slash is frowned upon?

Comment: Tried id with both the ending slash and without it. Restarted it afterwards to be sure. Same result. This is getting really frustrating.

Comment: Try replacing the path with *only* the `xampp` directory.  You can do this in the command shell so there's no need to trash your computer's environment or restart.  I assume you are trying to run `php` from the shell rather than the windows 'run' dialog.  This might seem like a weird thing to ask, but does it work if you use an explict path: `c:\xampp\php\php.exe -v`?

Comment: Ending slash is not a problem with Win7 at least (by default PATH contains `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ `), and a restart is most definitely *not* required! Only the command prompt window needs to be closed and reopened for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @paddy: yes, that displays the php install info. But isn't the environment variable's purpose to allow me using 'php' command anywhere in cmd ?

Comment: @zubzob You only answered the least interesting part of my comment.  Can you comment on the rest?  We're trying to work out what's going on because there's not enough information in your question, or even your comments.  My suggestions are not solutions - they are an attempt to isolate the issue.  You need to state whether any assumptions we have made are true or false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works now. The problem was that extra slash at the end (in the PATH environment variable).

I tried with:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\xampp\php\
```

but it didn't work, then with

> C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin; C:\xampp\php

but it didn't work also (notice the extra space before 'C:..').

Eventually,

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\xampp\php
```

did the trick.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me :( Any other tips?

Comment: @Enke try adding full path `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`, This could be the problem/